# tshark follow TCP stream upon condition

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I want to dump in a one-liner all TCP traffic of a stream after a specific condition. In other words, I want to do something like:

```
tshark -i wlan0 -s 0 -z follow,tcp,raw,x

x=`tshark -i wlan0 -s 0 -Y 'http.request.full_uri contains "blah-blah" and http.request.method == GET' -n -Tfields -e tcp.stream`
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with further information is given at: https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/49283/tshark-follow-tcp-stream-upon-condition